# How to update node version on Google Cloud Shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, nvm, google-cloud-shell

I'm using Google Cloud Shell, and the default node version is 12.14.1. Is there an easy way to update the node version to 14.x or 16.x?

`node` seems to be installed with `nvm`

```
$ which node
/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/node
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nvm` isn't a file, but a bash function and is exposed via `/google/devshell/bashrc.google.d/nvm`.

This script is sourced by default by `/google/devshell/bashrc.google`. However, I inadvertently commented out these lines, which disabled it

```
if [ -f "/google/devshell/bashrc.google" ]; then
  source /google/devshell/bashrc.google
fi
```

For anyone who's curious, those lines are put in there by `/etc/profile.d/restore_bashrc.sh`.

If you ran into a similar issue and want to fix it manually, you can add the following lines to your `.bashrc`

```
for FILE in /google/devshell/bashrc.google.d/*; do
  if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
    source "$FILE"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 8):

Apparently one can simply use `nvm` command to change the version.  When I tried:

```
nvm install 14
```

I was upgraded to 14.  I think I can install/change my node versions as desired.

Comment: thanks - when I tried that, I got `nvm: command not found`.

Comment: @TriNguyen Kindly restart the cloud shell and try the above command. It should work fine.

Comment: @DebdutGoswami I did. No dice. Can someone share with me the full path to `nvm`?

Comment: it works for me thanks,

Answer (score 0):

### Dec, 2021 Update:

[image]

This installs **the latest LTS version**:

```
nvm install 16.13.1
```

If you don't mind **the specific version**:

```
nvm install 16
```

In addition, this installs **the latest Current version**:

```
nvm install 17.3.0
```

If you don't mind **the specific version**:

```
nvm install 17
```